# If the opportunity is inactive for 2 days, send a notification to the Opportunity owner

Tags: process-builder

If the opportunity is inactive for 2 days, send a notification to the Opportunity owner....Started the work with Last activity Date in Opportunity process builder
This is the criteria of the process builder i done for this task But it is not working ..How would i solve this problem and what condition could be given here ..Please any one here[image] Help me!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by having time dependent action in process builder or time dependent workflow action.

The criteria for step will be if opportunity status is InActive and Last Activity change date field is updated then trigger a time dependent action in process builder by having a criteria like after 2 days of Last Activity Date.

Try to create one custom field. I have tried this by creating one custom field called Last Activity Date and i am able to select that field from the drop down.
[image]

Comment: Yes I  tried but Last Activity Date is not accessible in Time dependent Action

Comment: I have updated the answer hope it helps!!

Comment: Ok for sure and i would like to know what the value this field   Last Activity Date  holds and when this value get updated ?

Comment: Hi Last Activity Date field will hold the last activity happens on opportunity and this date will be updated whenever a new activity is created related to opportunity.

Comment: would u mind sharing that please?Actually i created a formula field which is equals opportunity Last Activity Field and  scheduled process based that field for 2 days but still didn't worked

Comment: Formula Field will not work in process builder and work flow rule because update of formula field value will not trigger any trigger/workflow/process builder.

Create a trigger on Task or Event, and write a code to update the Last Activity Date Custom Field on opportunity with activity date.

Can you please provide the entry criteria of process builder.

Comment: Thank u Manish,If the opportunity is inactive for 2 days, send a notification to the Opportunity owner--This is what actually has to be done.And an email Templete and Email alert is created for this.Also it should not be work when Opportunity Stage is Closed Won/Lost